# There's a problem when im inputting username to store to a file but it won't store

Tags: c, function, fgets

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void tampilan_awal()
{
    int angka_daerah;
    do {
    printf("Daerah\n.....................................\n1. Daerah\n");
    printf("Ketik angka 1 jika ingin memilih daerah yang dituju dan angka 0 jika tidak ingin melanjutkan!\n"); //Click 1 if you wanna choose destination(daerah) you wanna go and click 0 if you don't want to continue
    scanf("%i", &angka_daerah);
    if(angka_daerah == 1)
    {
        pilihdaerahutama();
    } else if(angka_daerah == 0)
    {
        break;
    }
    } while (angka_daerah != 1 && angka_daerah != 0);
}

void daftar_akun_database() {
    FILE *filePointer;
    char username[30];
    char password[30];

    // Buka file untuk menulis
    filePointer = fopen("`touch filename.txt`", "a");

    printf("Buat username dan password\n");

    printf("Username: ");
    fgets(username, sizeof(username), stdin);
    clearBuffer();

    printf("Password: ");
    fgets(password, sizeof(password), stdin);
    clearBuffer();

    // Menghapus karakter newline dari username dan password
    strtok(username, "\n");
    strtok(password, "\n");

    fprintf(filePointer, "Username: %s\nPassword: %s\n", username, password);

    fclose(filePointer);

    filePointer = fopen("filename.txt", "r");
    fseek(filePointer, 0, SEEK_SET);

    check_database();
}


void clearBuffer() {
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
}

void check_database() {
    FILE *filePointer;
    char username[50];
    char line[50];
    char password[50];
    bool found = false;
    int punya_akun;

    // Buka file untuk membaca
    filePointer = fopen("filename.txt", "r");

    // Periksa keberhasilan pembukaan file
    if (filePointer == NULL) {
        printf("Gagal membuka file.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Meminta pengguna untuk memasukkan username dan password
    printf("Masukkan username dan password\n");
    printf("Masukkan username: ");
    fgets(username, sizeof(username), stdin);
    clearBuffer();
    strtok(username, "\n"); // Menghapus newline

    printf("Masukkan password: ");
    fgets(password, sizeof(password), stdin);
    clearBuffer();
    strtok(password, "\n"); // Menghapus newline

    // Loop untuk membaca setiap baris dari file
        while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), filePointer) != NULL) {
        // Menghapus karakter newline dari setiap baris
            strtok(line, "\n");

        // Memeriksa apakah username dan password ada dalam baris
            if (strstr(line, "Username: ") != NULL && strstr(line, username) != NULL &&
                fgets(line, sizeof(line), filePointer) != NULL && // Membaca baris Password
                strstr(line, "Password: ") != NULL && strstr(line, password) != NULL) {
                printf("Username dan password benar!\n");
                found = true;
                tampilan_awal();

        }
    }
    if(!found)
    {
        printf("Username tidak dapat ditemukan silahkan coba lagi.\n");
        do{
        printf("Sudah punya akun? Silahkan ketik 1 untuk daftar dan 2 untuk coba lagi: ");
        scanf("%i", &punya_akun);
        if(punya_akun == 1)
        {
            daftar_akun_database();
        } else{
            check_database();
        }
        } while(punya_akun != 1 && punya_akun != 2);
    }
  

    fclose(filePointer);

}

int main()
{
    check_database();
    return 0;
}
```

i don't know what's wrong with my code :(, the lecturer didn't teaching the f gets and gets function properly, they do it in such a rush. They recommend me using gets, while i just know f gets because i study at w3schools. Can someone give me the correct code and which area i did wrong?? im so clueless and the deadline is tomorrow(we have to presented it online)

i tried input the username and password but on the file there's no username at all. just like this
Username:
Password: 1234

i think this has something to do with the fgets and the function clearBuffer but i have no idea where is exactly wrong. The function clearBuffer just made some new space like if we go to the check_database function it showed like this
Username: 1234 (enter)
(enter)
Password: 5678 (enter)
(enter)

I do not understand what is happening, can someone explain this to me???

Comment: `fgets()` reads  a line.  If you want to read a block use `read()` or process the file line by line.

Comment: If your function doesn't take any arguments declare it as a `(void)` instead of `()`.

Comment: In general you want to resolve all compiler warnings.

Comment: We can't compile your code without the definition `tampilan_awal()`.  This tells you never build what you share with us.  That's the bare minimum.

Comment: Delete the comment and edit the question instead with this info.

Comment: Your program requires the file filename.txt.  You should tell us what that file contains (i.e. `touch filename.txt`).

Comment: The file actually contains nothing, i have to input it on the program first and then stored it to the file like i said before it's look like this. Username: (myinput) (Enter) Password: (myinput) I'm sorry im new here, so i don't know features in stackoverflow

Comment: The file doesn't exist so your program will terminate with an error.  Revise question so we know what input it requires.

Comment: Im kinda don't understood, what should i do?? should i write the link to the file in the question???

Comment: Edit your question to tell us that we need to create the empty file `filename.txt`.  On linux it would be `touch filename.txt`.

Comment: @VLL `strtok` modifies the string, no matter whether you use the return value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `check_database()` you read a line with `fgets()` which consumes the trailing `\n`.  Then you call `clearBuffer()` which will block in `getchar()` till the stream is closed with Ctrl-D to generate the EOF as there is no `\n` left in the stream.  Simply don't call `clearBuffer()` after reading a line with `fgets()`.

Here are some other issues:

1. `strtok(username, "\n")` is a slightly strange way to strip the trailing newline of a non-empty line (`"...\n"`) and it doesn't strip it from an empty line (`"\n"`).  Consider using this instead:

   ```
   #define strip(s) (s)[strcspn((s), "\n")]='\0'
   // ..
   strip(username);
   ```
2. If user is not found in the database (as it starts out empty) you provide the option to write it.  You should close the file before calling `daftar_akun_database()`, or even better open the file in `main()` and pass it to the functions that need access to it.
3. In `main()` you call `check_database()` from `main()` but then loop forever in the bottom by calling `check_database()` recursively.  Eventually it will run of stack space.  It's better to call `daftar_akun_database()` if you need to and then return and have the loop in `main()` instead.  It's also odd that you call `check_database()` from `daftar_akun_database()` so don't do that.
4. In `check_database()` you `return 1` but the function is declared as not returning anything.  It should just be `return`.
5. In `check_database()` you should call `clearBuffer()` after `scanf("%i", &punya_akun)`.
6. If the user is not found, I think, option 1 is meant to write it.  You should pass the `username` and `password` to `daftar_akun_database()` instead of asking the user for the same information again.
7. (Not fixed) Always check the return value from I/O functions like `fgets()`, `scanf()` etc.
8. (Not fixed) Use symbolic constants instead of magic values (`50`).  It's not a big deal in your program as you use`sizeof` when calling `fgets()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define PATH "filename.txt"
#define strip(s) (s)[strcspn((s), "\n")]='\0'

void check_database(FILE *database);
void clearBuffer(void);
void daftar_akun_database(FILE *database, const char *usernmame, const char *password);
void tampilan_awal();

void check_database(FILE *database) {
    char username[50];
    char line[50];
    char password[50];
    bool found = false;
    int punya_akun;

    // Meminta pengguna untuk memasukkan username dan password
    printf("Masukkan username dan password\n");
    printf("Masukkan username: ");
    fgets(username, sizeof(username), stdin);
    strip(username);

    printf("Masukkan password: ");
    fgets(password, sizeof(password), stdin);
    strip(password);

    // Loop untuk membaca setiap baris dari file
    rewind(database);
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), database) != NULL) {
        strip(line);
        // Memeriksa apakah username dan password ada dalam baris
        if (strstr(line, "Username: ") != NULL && strstr(line, username) != NULL &&
            fgets(line, sizeof(line), database) != NULL && // Membaca baris Password
            strstr(line, "Password: ") != NULL && strstr(line, password) != NULL) {
            printf("Username dan password benar!\n");
            found = true;
            tampilan_awal();

        }
    }
    if(!found) {
        printf("Username tidak dapat ditemukan silahkan coba lagi.\n");
        for(;;) {
            printf("Sudah punya akun? Silahkan ketik 1 untuk daftar dan 2 untuk coba lagi: ");
            scanf("%i", &punya_akun);
            clearBuffer();
            if(punya_akun == 1) {
                daftar_akun_database(database, username, password);
                break;
            } else if(punya_akun == 2)
                break;
        }
    }
}

void clearBuffer(void) {
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
}

void daftar_akun_database(FILE *database, const char *username, const char *password) {
    fseek(database, 0, SEEK_END);
    fprintf(database, "Username: %s\nPassword: %s\n", username, password);
}


// implementation was not provided initially
void tampilan_awal() {}

int main() {
    FILE *database = fopen(PATH, "a+");
    if(!database) {
        printf("Gagal membuka file.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    for(;;)
        check_database(database);
    return 0;
}
```

and example session:

```
$ rm filename.txt
$ ./a.out
Masukkan username dan password
Masukkan username: bob 
Masukkan password: pass
Username tidak dapat ditemukan silahkan coba lagi.
Sudah punya akun? Silahkan ketik 1 untuk daftar dan 2 untuk coba lagi: 1
Masukkan username dan password
Masukkan username: bob2
Masukkan password: pass
Username tidak dapat ditemukan silahkan coba lagi.
Sudah punya akun? Silahkan ketik 1 untuk daftar dan 2 untuk coba lagi: 2
Masukkan username dan password
Masukkan username: bob 
Masukkan password: pass
Username dan password benar!
Masukkan username dan password
```

Comment: Hello sir Allan, im already fix the code with your suggestion it just needs a few of change like changing the `strtok(username, "\n")` to `username[strcspn(username, "\n")] = '\0';`  thankyou so much for your help!! do you perhaps have a web or youtube channel recommendations for me to study about c language?? my final test coming up in 2 weeks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list is a list.  I like The C Programming Language (2nd Edition) but it's a bit dated now so you need to learn about initialization like https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/initialization.  Work more practice problems and learn how to debug your program.  For your original problem try to print out the username.  If that works then you know it's in `clearBuffer()`.  Then add some print statements to `clearBuffer()`.  If you repeat yourself consider writing a function and call that instead of duplicate code.

Comment: Good luck on your test.

Comment: @Gerhardh Revised answer accordingly.  Thanks.